# How do I use a converted jpgData image in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When the user selects an item from their photo library, the app saves the UIImage to the app's directory using the following code:

```
let imageUUID = UUID()
    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(imageUUID)")
    
    guard let uiImage = newImage else { return}
    
    if let jpegData = uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
        try? jpegData.write(to: filename, options: [.atomicWrite, .completeFileProtection])
    }
```

How can I use the saved image in a view?
Thanks!

Comment: Note that I have edited out the part where you ask for Core Data tutorials, since asking for off-site resources is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should save the UUID somewhere so that you can read the file later. This could be in `UserDefaults`, a JSON file, CoreData, or whatever, depending on your needs.

Suppose you have the path to the file stored in `filePath`, you can create an `Image` like this:

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath) ?? UIImage())
```

This will use an empty image as fallback if it failed to read the file.

Comment: Thank you! I have the UUID saved in a JSON file along with some other data, also encoded and saved in the filepath.

Comment: My bad- I forgot to do that haha

Answer (score 0):

Following code convert UIImage to Image in SwiftUI:

```
let uiImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) ?? UIImage() // Access it from your storage
let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
```

There are different UIImage initializer methods available, you can use any one of them to get UIImage instance.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image

You will like this tutorial of `Coredata` with `SwiftUI`: https://www.raywenderlich.com/9335365-core-data-with-swiftui-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: @jasnzhng Updated code with tutorials for coredata + swiftui